# Remove degree markers in matplotlib plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, axis-labels, polar-coordinates

I have created a spider plot with `matplotlib` but I can't figure out how to get rid of the degree markers that is overlapping the label text I have added.  I am having to use `matplotlib` v3.2.1 due to some other compatibility issues. I need some help figuring out how to get rid of the 0deg, 45deg, 90deg, ect. labels.

```
chart = plt.figure(figsize=(15,8.5), dpi=150, facecolor=('#D3D3D3'), edgecolor='#000000')
ax = chart.add_subplot(111,polar=True)
ax.set_facecolor('grey')
ax.set_ylim(0,5.1)
ax.set_yticklabels([])

# set guidelines below each of the bars
for i in range(len(dataset['Console'])-1):
    ax.vlines(x=Console_loc, ymin=0, ymax=5.1, colors='#D3D3D3', linewidths=.75, alpha=.5, zorder=1)

# Robust Line
ax.plot(resolution, robust, alpha=1, ls='dashed', lw=2, color='#145a32', label='Good')
# 2874A6

# Stable Line
ax.plot(resolution, stable, alpha=1, lw=2, color='#000000',label='Ok')

# 6 Month Avg
# 5DADE2 - cyan
fill = '#7Fb3D5'
ax.plot(Console_loc, dataset['Average'], alpha=.45, color=fill, label='6 month avg')
ax.fill(Console_loc, dataset['Average'], alpha=.35, color=fill)

# Current Month Bars
ax.bar(x=Console_loc, height=dataset['Current'], width=dataset['Bar_Width'], color=dataset['Bar_Color'], label='Current Month', edgecolor=dataset['Border_Color'])

# plot console labels on graph
yloc = 5.3

for i in range(len(dataset['Console'])-1):
    if round(np.degrees(Console_loc[i]),1) in np.arange(112.5,270,22.5):
        plt.text(x=Console_loc[i],y=yloc, s=dataset['Console'].str[:-5].iloc[i], ha='right', va='center')
    elif round(np.degrees(Console_loc[i]),1) in np.arange(292.5,360,22.5) or np.degrees(Console_loc[i]) in np.arange(0,90,22.5):
        plt.text(x=Console_loc[i],y=yloc, s=dataset['Console'].str[:-5].iloc[i], ha='left', va='center')
    else:
        plt.text(x=Console_loc[i],y=yloc, s=dataset['Console'].str[:-5].iloc[i], ha='center', va='center')

# clear angles on outside of chart
# empt = []*17
 lines,labels = plt.thetagrids(angles=np.degrees(Console_loc), labels=dataset['Console'], alpha=.001)


# add chart title text
plt.text(x=np.radians(137), y=8.3, s='Testing chart', ha='right', va='center', fontsize='x-large')

plt.grid(False)
plt.legend(loc=(1.2,.8))
plt.show()
```

Image:

[image: Spider plot generated]